# Ms-Access 2016 Returns Corrupted Data on DAO.Recordset OpenRecordset(

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error, type-mismatch

The following code was working correctly with Access 2007. When I use it on Access 2016, it returns a corrupted data and even cause the whole MS Access to close and restart

```
Dim mywork As Workspace
Dim mydb As DAO.Database
Dim TB As DAO.Recordset
Dim crt As Double
Dim ODC As Double  
Dim ES As Double 
Dim SC As Double  
Dim PA As Double  
Dim PT As Double 
Dim SU As Double 
Dim WT As Double 
Dim SI As Double 
Set mywork = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set mydb = CurrentDb()

ES = Me![EngineSize]
SC = Nz(Me![SeatsPsngrs], 0)
PA = Me![PricingArea].Column(0)
PT = Me![PLATE_TYPE].Column(0)
SU = Me![SP_Use].Column(0)
WT = Me![Weight]
SI = Me![FSUM_INSURED]
'------------------------------
 Set TB = mydb.OpenRecordset("SELECT INSPAL_ACT_TP_TARRIF.* FROM INSPAL_ACT_TP_TARRIF " & vbCrLf & _
 "WHERE (((INSPAL_ACT_TP_TARRIF.ACT_USE)= " & PT & " ) AND ((INSPAL_ACT_TP_TARRIF.ACT_SP_USE)= " & SU & ") " & vbCrLf & _
 "AND ((Int(nz([ACT_CC_FR],0)))<= " & ES & ") AND ((Int(nz([ACT_CC_TO])))>= " & ES & ") " & vbCrLf & _
 "AND ((Int(nz([ACT_LOAD_FR],0)))<= " & WT & ") AND ((Int(nz([ACT_LOAD_TO],0)))>= " & WT & ")" & vbCrLf & _
 "AND ((Int(nz([ACT_PASS_FR],0)))<= " & SC & ") AND ((Int(nz([ACT_PASS_TO],0)))>= " & SC & ") " & vbCrLf & _
 "AND ((INSPAL_ACT_TP_TARRIF.ACT_LIST_DT)>#3/1/2010#)" & vbCrLf & _
 "AND ((INSPAL_ACT_TP_TARRIF.ACT_LOC)=" & PA & " " & "))", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges, dbOptimistic)

'----------------------------------

Me![PRD_VALUE1F] = Round(Nz(TB![ACT_ACT], 0) * 0.5474)
```

Comment: What is the code doing? What error are you getting? What have you tried?

Comment: Runtime Error raised  on Me![PRD_VALUE1F] = Round(Nz(TB![ACT_ACT], 0) * 0.5474) , then Ms access Hangup and restart  , I try to msgbox the value TB![ACT_ACT] , it display ?? instead of the original value which it's 23

Answer (score 0):

thanks , it was a Microsoft Bug

### This would appear to be a new bug introduced by the latest round of updates.  The best you can do right now is revert your office installation to a prior build no.  Refer to Access – Version 2005 Build No. 12827.20268 Causing Problems

As of today, if you are on version 2005, build 12827.20010 or greater, and you manipulate Decimal fields (Access DataType=Number/FieldSize=Decimal, or SQL DataType=Decimal) using DAO (Data Access Objects), you might have identified your app crashing. If you hover a variable with the type in VBA code, you may see that the field is not being displayed properly; either reading as ‘?????’ or giving a Type Mismatch error, or Access may crash.